# How does one show that $a \in S?$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f:J \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous real-valued function such that $\alpha = f(j)$ for some $j \in J.$ Let $S=f^{-1}(\{\alpha\}).$ Show that if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $S$ converging to an element $a \in J,$ then $a \in S.$

I was trying to do this, but I don't know how to approach this. I think I have to prove that $S$ is closed and $\{\alpha \} \in f(J) \subseteq \mathbb R.$ We know that $\{\alpha \}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb R,$ so $f^{-1}(\{\alpha \})$ is a closed set (by the continuity of $f$). Is this what's happening?

Comment: Yes, $\{\alpha\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$, so $S$ is closed in $J$ by continuity. I'm assuming $J$ is some topological space?

Comment: No no J is a subset of R. That's why i am confused what to do

Comment: That's fine; $J$ has the subspace topology.

Comment: Ok thank you then

Comment: I would say use the def'n of continuity but there are many equivalent def'ns, including even what you want to prove, so please add which def'n of continuity you are starting from.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Since $\{\alpha\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuous, so $S= f^{-1}(\{\alpha\})$ is closed in $J.$ Therefore $a \in \overline{S}=S.$